# Dual screen: same monitor, different resolutions

Tags: raspbian, hdmi, pi-4

I have two identical screens (2 cheap b07k32m4lj)

https://www.amazon.it/Longruner-Monitor-Display-800x480-Raspberry/dp/B07K32M4LJ

i'm trying to set them up to be both **1280x720** and show the same image (duplicate screen)

i've tried the following methods:

## 1: edit /boot/config.txt

as follows:

```
framebuffer_width=1280
framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
hdmi_cvt=1280 720 60
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
```

Now screens resolution are different (the first is **1280x720**, the second is **800x480**)

## 2: edid file via tvservice

after running the following command:

```
tvservice -d edid.dat
```

I got the file **edid.dat** and then added these lines to **/boot/config.txt**

```
hdmi_edid_file:1=1
hdmi_edid_filename:1=edid.dat
hdmi_force_hotplug:1=1
```

now I have this situation in the **screen configuration** utility:

[image]

the resoultion of the second monitor is now **1024x768** (still not what I need) while the first is still **1280x720**.

Any advice on how to solve this problem?

Comment: the website says that the LCDs are 800x480 ... are you absolutely certain that you have two identical monitors?

Comment: @jsotola yes it's correct, the monitors are natively 800*480, but I managed to make the first to work at 1280*720... Now i'm trying to do the same with the second (I know this is some kind of forcing but i'm doing this 'cause i've developed an app in Python which has a fixed resolution of 1280*720)

Comment: have you tried switching the monitors around? ... there may be a difference in hardware